# How to find offending class from obfuscated error message

Tags: android, proguard

I have a crash in my android app, which results in the following stack trace.
The app is proguarded and I have the mapping file. The stacktrace is correctly deobfuscated as you can see, except the message of the `IllegalStateException`. The name of the Fragment there is still `a`. How can I figure out which fragment is actually causing the problem in order to fix the problem. I have my suspicions, but this is a rather large app and I use a lot of fragments in there. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the crash - it happens in the wild.

I have searched for all occurrences of `Fragment -> a` or `Fragment -> **.a` and have found some possibilities, but I am still not sure, I am looking at the correct one.

So I have two questions:

1. Can I somehow deobfuscate the a from the message?
2. Is there a tool where I can load the mapping and visualise all classes that were obfuscated to `a`?

The already deobfuscated stack trace (with the `a` in the message):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: a{957db5c} (3bdece50-8a03-4b3b-aca9-85a6d2be9e93) id=0x7f09019d}
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.addFragment(FragmentStore.java:67)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1563)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:405)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

The obfuscated stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: a{957db5c} (3bdece50-8a03-4b3b-aca9-85a6d2be9e93) id=0x7f09019d}
    at l0.l.d.a0.a(FragmentStore.java:7)
    at l0.l.d.r.b(FragmentManager.java:4)
    at l0.l.d.a.m(BackStackRecord.java:27)
    at l0.l.d.r.C(FragmentManager.java:51)
    at l0.l.d.r.Y(FragmentManager.java:10)
    at l0.l.d.r.B(FragmentManager.java:14)
    at l0.l.d.r$d.run(FragmentManager.java:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your first question, but I know Google play console allows you to load the mapping and visualize all classes that were obfuscated.

Comment: This setting seems to be gone from the  new Play Console

Comment: You can switch back to the old play console by changing it in your settings.

Comment: ok, uploaded the mapping file, but I don't see an option to visualise the mappings and search for them? Did you  mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid deobfuscation won't fix your problem because the printed line

```
Fragment already added: a{957db5c} (3bdece50-8a03-4b3b-aca9-85a6d2be9e93) id=0x7f09019d}
```

is a string generated in run time using your class name. you can check the method which generates this string in [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java#659).
you can set a tag for your fragments and then you can find out which fragments is added twice.

Comment: That is what I feared. Is there a way to visualise the mapping though? I can't find a tool to do that. In the new Play Console there is no "Deobfuscate proguard" setting anymore